# What are some books on Emunah?

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, faith-bitachon-emunah

Does anyone have any names of books related to faith and Emunah?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Sagi and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us! Hopefully your now edited question will get reopened so you can get good answers.

Comment: It might be useful to specify if you read Hebrew or are looking for English books.

Comment: The Chazon Ish's Emunah U'bitachon is a classic, although if you don't read high level hebrew it may be too difficult. I have heard there is an english version though.